# Django channels ProtocolTypeRouter unit testing with pytest

Tags: django-channels

I am checking out channels for the next project. But I am stuck at unit testing the basics. I guess it must be something I keep overlooking.

**Versions:**

- channels==2.1.7
- django==2.1.3

**routing.py**

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter #, URLRouter
from Phoenix.ProtocolTestConsumer import ProtocolTestConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)

    "test": ProtocolTestConsumer,
})
```

**ProtocolTestConsumer.py**

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from django.conf import settings
from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer

class ProtocolTestConsumer(SyncConsumer):
    def test_a(self, event):
        logging.debug("consumer test_a {}".format(event))

    def test_b(self, event):
        logging.debug("consumer test_b {}".format(event))

    def test_c(self, event):
        logging.debug("consumer test_c {}".format(event))
```

**test_ProtocolTestConsumer.py**

```
import pytest
import logging

from Phoenix.ProtocolTestConsumer import ProtocolTestConsumer
from channels.testing import ApplicationCommunicator

communicator = ApplicationCommunicator(ProtocolTestConsumer, {"type": "test"})

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_call_a():
    await communicator.send_input(
        {"type": "test.a",
         "text": "Blue"})
    logging.debug("pytest is printing this")
```

**DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings pytest -s -v**

```
== test session starts ==
platform linux -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.1.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.1 -- /home/user/src/web/Phoenix/venv-phoenix/bin/python3.7
cachedir: .pytest_cache
Django settings: web.settings (from environment variable)
rootdir: /home/user/src/web/Phoenix/web/Phoenix, inifile:
plugins: django-3.4.5, asyncio-0.10.0
collected 1 item                                                                                        

test_ProtocolTestConsumer.py::test_call_a DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:root:pytest is printing this
PASSED

== 1 passed in 0.24 seconds ==
```

I expected to see more console output from the Consumer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues I see in your code. First, your routing seems to be missing some parts. The consumer should be wrapped first as a django url before passing it to the protocol type router. Like this:

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)

    "test": [
        path('test/', ProtocolTestConsumer)
    ]
})
```

The first 'test' is doing a protocol routing while the second is doing a normal django url routing.

Secondly, when intializing your communicator, you should use the url of the consumer:

```
ApplicationCommunicator(ProtocolTestConsumer, "test/")
```

**EDIT**

After carefully looking at your code, I saw that it in fact correctly implemented, just on a lower level making it a protocol of its own like websocket and HTTP. 
Your mistkake however, is that you're not receiving output after the call to `send_output`. The send_output call just puts the message on the queue. The `receive_output` then retrieves the first message on top of the queue which triggers a call to the respective method in the consumer.

Therefore, you need to receive the output in your test code this way:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_call_a():
    await communicator.send_input(
        {"type": "test.a",
         "text": "Blue"})
    logging.debug("pytest is printing this")
    response = await communicator.receive_output()
```

You can check the implementation of the `WebsocketCommunicator` and `HttpCommunicator` for more details on how they send and receive messages

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But no output from the consumer.

I came to the routing part

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But no output from the consumer.

Explenation why I came to the routing part. Because this is working for me using 'https://github.com/ruralscenery/channels_mqtt'. This in place and working, now I would like to get the consumer unit tested without connecting to a mqtt broker. This led to the test consumer setup above.

Comment: @user1723256 check my edit. That should solve it. I tested it myself

Comment: Now I have the `response = await communicator.receive_output()` 
and got a message ">               await getter
E               RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<test_call_a() running at /home/user/src/web/Phoenix/web/Phoenix/test_ProtocolTestConsumer.py:15> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:158]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/queues.py:159: RuntimeError
"

Comment: Have to figure out what that means.

Comment: @user1723256 I suspect this is some issue with the async io event loop. The communicator is asynchronous but the consumer is synchronous. Not exactly sure how it is causing this issue but it maybe connected. I added the methods you have to an existing AysncConsumer and setup another routing similar to yours and the print statements worked. Try switching to AsyncConsumer to see if it helps